# custom dialog Mahapps ShowMetroDialogAsync with close button

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mahapps.metro

I create Mahapps custom dialog message with this code. the problem is the dialog form not show close button so cant close it.
how to show close button ?

```
        public async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    

  {      Button btn = (Button) sender;
        //dialog.Resources["CustomDialogTest"];
        string[] id =  btn.Name.ToString().Split('_');

        this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented;
        var dialog = (BaseMetroDialog)this.Resources["CustomDialogTest"];

        var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "OK",
            AnimateShow = true,
            NegativeButtonText = "Go away!",
            FirstAuxiliaryButtonText = "Cancel",               
        };


         await this.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog);
         // this for close the dialog -> await this.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialog);           
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `CustomDialogTest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed a custom Input Dialog. So I created a `CustomInputDialog` class inherited from `BaseMetroDialog`.

I used this code to call the method:

```
public async Task<string> ShowCustomDialog(string message, string title)
{
    var metroDialogSettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
    {
        AffirmativeButtonText = "OK",
        NegativeButtonText = "CANCEL",
        AnimateHide = true,
        AnimateShow = true,
        ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented,
    };

    var dialog = new CustomInputDialog(View, metroDialogSettings)
    {
        Message = message,
        Title = title,
        Input = metroDialogSettings.DefaultText
    };

    return await InvokeOnCurrentDispatcher(async () =>
    {
        await View.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog, metroDialogSettings);

        await dialog.WaitForButtonPressAsync().ContinueWith((m) =>
        {
            InvokeOnCurrentDispatcher(() => View.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialog));
        });

        return dialog.Input;
    });
}
```

Message, Title and Input are dependency properties of CustomInputDialog. This is working at my end.

Comment: How you are closing the dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Add close button to your dialog (which is in `Resources`) & hook up its `Click` event to close your dialog. For closing, use `this.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialog);` where `this` is `MetroWindow` instance.